# Both onBlur and onChange not working with <input type="text"

Tags: javascript

I have a standard input type text field that is supposed to trigger a Javascript whenever it is changed. First I tried onChange, however it just did nothing. Then I tried onBlur, but also here it did not do anything.

HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" size="1" class="inputbox" onblur="c();" name="qty" value="1" />
```

The Javascript should not be the problem, because I am triggering this with another select dropdown menu as well and there it works fine! Just on this text field it seems not to work. Anyways, here's the Javascript code:

```
function c() {
$('#add4').fadeOut(function(){
        $('#add5').css('visibility', 'visible');
        document.u.submit();
}); 
}
```

I checked online, but could not find any relevant posts or hints in this regard whatsoever. Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Remove the inline event handler and use proper event handlers, and it will probably work, as I'm guessing wildly you put the c() function inside document ready or something else strange.

Comment: @adeneo, you should make your comment an answer.

Comment: Is there an error in the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
<form>
<input id="target" type="text" value="Field 1">
<input type="text" value="Field 2">
</form>
<div id="other">
Trigger the handler
</div>
The event handler can be bound to the first input field:
$( "#target" ).blur(function() {
alert( "Handler for .blur() called." );
});
```

check this links for your reference http://api.jquery.com/blur/

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_blur_alert

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks magExp! I saw a comment above which explained the same approach, but the person could have been more friendly. Anyways, I rewrote with a handler and now it works fine. Still strange that the inline would not. :/

Answer (score -1):

This may solve your problem:

```
<input type="text" size="1" class="inputbox" onblur=" javascript:c(); " name="qty" value="1" />
```